# Creating a list with user input? Sales program, enter sales for 7 days

Tags: python, list, user-input

So the problem is this:

Design a program that asks the user to enter a store’s sales for each day of the week. The amounts should be stored in an array. Use a loop to calculate the total sales for the week and display the result.

This is what I have so far,

```
maxValue = 7
sales = 0
index = 0
totalSales = [maxValue]

for index in range(0, maxValue - 1):
    totalSales[index] = float(input("Enter today's sales: $"))
```

I know it's in issue with bounds, I am getting the error *IndexError: list assignment index out of range* after I enter my second input.

After debugging I can see that totalSale =  [maxValue] is giving the list a length of one.. but I don't understand how to fix this. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is at this line:

```
totalSales = [maxValue]
```

The line basically sets `[7]` to the variable `totalSales`. What you are looking for is the `*` operation on a list to generate a list of your desired length filled with null *(`None`)* values:

```
maxValue = 7
sales = 0
index = 0
totalSales = [None] * maxValue

for index in range(maxValue):
    totalSales[index] = float(input("Enter today's sales: $"))
```

Or better, use the [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method:

```
maxValue = 7
sales = 0
index = 0
totalSales = []

for index in range(maxValue):
    totalSales.append(float(input("Enter today's sales: $")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
maxValue = 7
sales = 0
index = 0
totalSales = list()
```

[maxValue] would add just one item of value `maxValue` to the list. Append adds new items to the list. For range, you can just use the `maxValue` as a parameter, no need for (0, maxValue)

```
for index in range(maxValue):
    totalSales.append(float(input("Enter today's sales: $")))
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Adam.Er8, use the `append()` function to add the entries to the list. You almost had it! Also, the call to the `range()` function will exclude the "nth" index, so you do not need to subtract one from maxValue to get 7 entries. Example below:

```
total_sales = []
for ix in range(0, maxValue):
    totalSales.append(float(input("Enter today's sales: $")))

# results below
# Enter today's sales: $10
# Enter today's sales: $5
# Enter today's sales: $10
# Enter today's sales: $1
# Enter today's sales: $1
# Enter today's sales: $2
# Enter today's sales: $3

# total_sales
# [10.0, 5.0, 10.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```